# Liferay.Language.get("key") is not working in Javascript anymore since Liferay 7.3+

Tags: liferay

I had liferay 7.0, when you open the ispect ( Ctrl + Shift + I) then go to the console and write

for english

Liferay.Language.get('login');

"Login"

german language

Liferay.Language.get('login');

"Anmelden"

But Now when I upgraded to Liferay 7.4 , I get

for english

Liferay.Language.get('login');

"login"

german language

Liferay.Language.get('login')

"login"

[image]

The issue has been reported
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-123191?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403607020813-Liferay-Language-get-method-is-no-longer-working-with-string-variables-as-of-DXP-7-3

Comment: [Please note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)

Answer (score 1):

From [one of the comments](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-123191?focusedCommentId=2331376#comment-2331376) in the tickets that you've linked yourself:

> That option was deprecated under LPS-113569 and is no longer available. You can get some extra information in the pull request deprecating such functionality:
>
> > Liferay.Language.get is replaced by the language filter and we also want to remove the AUI dependency, so in this change, we migrate the Liferay.Language.get function to frontend-js-web.
> >
> > Note that the migrated version is dumbed down to just return the key: it does not preserve the dubious fallback behavior of the old implementation, that used a deprecated synchronous request to the server to fetch the value, which would produce a console warning, and very likely end up returning the key anyway (unless the corresponding value happened to be in the kernel); in short, the old implementation only wallpapered over a real problem (failure of the filter to do its actual job).

One of the linked issues is about [updating the documentation](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LRDOCS-9143), which hasn't happened yet.

Edit, following your comment:

The documentation that you link in your comment looks like the not-yet-updated documentation.

In general, I've confirmed your statement (which wasn't a question, by the way): Indeed, the feature you've been using has become less and less useful (as it was only good for a few translations from core, never from any module, and retrieved them in a performance-killing way. It's not possible to extend it to retrieve all modules' keys and do so in a performant manner, so you should use whatever technique the libraries you're using to translate your frontend are using)

In case you're building your UI with JSPs, that would be `<liferay-ui:message key="your-key-of-choice"/>`. In other cases, you know what you're using, and that framework definitely has means of providing localization.

Comment: sorry, I did not get your answer!
Do you mean I need to wait ? 
I found this doc as well 
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-docs/blob/master/en/developer/frameworks/articles/front-end-development/05-creating-js-widgets-with-js-tooling/04-localizing-your-widget.markdown

Comment: Thanks, for your clear answer, 
I am using angular and freemarker but in some area it is just javascript 
I will try to find a way to avoid using javascript

Comment: well, there are ways to localize javascript as well (and angular isn't that far away from javascript anyway)

Comment: can you provide me with a good way to localize ?

Comment: I'm not an angular guy, sorry. In fact, I'm not so much of a frontend guy... that would be a separate question like "how to I localize in angular?" - but that is likely well answered already in angular's documentation

Comment: I found a solution > 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@clavis/translation-transformer

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is true it does not work anymore, as Olaf Kock said , you need to implement a new way to localize javascript , there is a npm tool for this @clavis/translation-transformer

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: yes, the orginal problem has been solved in Liferay but not for community . 

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403607020813-Liferay-Language-get-method-is-no-longer-working-with-string-variables-as-of-DXP-7-3

the solution I have mentioned before is  > 

https://www.skypack.dev/view/@clavis/translation-transformer